# Json Schema Polymorphism Validate with anyOf

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I've got a `Pet` object that could be either a `dog` or a `cat`
Depending on what `noise` they make I'd like to then be able to validate other fields.
schema:

```
{
  "$id": "http://example.com",
  "definitions": {
    "pet": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "noise": {
          "enum": [
            "bark",
            "meow"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "dog": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/pet",
      "properties": {
        "noise": {
          "const": "bark"
        },
        "tail": {
          "enum": [
            "short",
            "long"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "cat": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/pet",
      "properties": {
        "noise": {
          "const": "meow"
        },
        "tail": {
          "enum": [
            "wavy",
            "slinky"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "pets": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/dog",
            "$ref": "#/definitions/cat"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works when running the following json through:

```
{"pets":[{"noise":"meow","tail":"wavy"}]}
```

but not when running:

```
{"pets":[{"noise":"bark","tail":"long"}]}
[$.pets[0].tail: does not have a value in the enumeration [wavy, slinky], $.pets[0].noise: must be a constant value meow]
```

or

```
{"pets":[{"noise":"bark","tail":"long"},{"noise":"meow","tail":"wavy"}]}
[$.pets[0].tail: does not have a value in the enumeration [wavy, slinky], $.pets[0].noise: must be a constant value meow]
```

I can get this working by using `if/else` in the json schema, but requires another type to avoid a circular dependency:

```
  "petWithConstraints": {
    "$ref":"#/definitions/pet",
    "allOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "noise": {
                "const": "bark"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/dog"
          }
        },
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "noise": {
                "const": "meow"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/cat"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

This means for every new definition it also requires another `if` statement.

Is there a better method of doing this? (without the extra definition/if statement)

Comment: Can you quantify "I don't feel it's as maintainable"? Otherwise, this could be seen as a subjective question.

Comment: updated, there's an example where this method works as well but another where it doesn't.

Comment: These are generally the two patterns used. I don't know why you consider the requirements add if statements problematic. It's like writing code, if you need a condition, you add an if block. Personally I find the structured approach you've taken to use more definitions preferable and more maintainable than it would be otherwise.

Comment: Why is it you think this is not ideal? If you could make it work any way you wanted, how would it look?

Comment: Because my real example isn't quite this simple with hundreds of combinations. I would not write code in that manner and prefer to fall back onto polymorphism to handle this. With the solution I have if I added another 'pet' `fish` I would only need to add a `fish` definition and not also add an `if` statement to the `petWithConstraints` definition (which I would no longer require)

Comment: Your initial example would be the equivalent of polymorphism. It sounds like you want to generate your schema JSON as opposed to write it by hand. You may find jsonnet useful.

Comment: I see the misunderstanding here... I was trying to get my initial example to work, not that I disagreed with it. As per my answer I've resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For those that come across this, this was a syntactical error.
Each ref should have been in it's own code block.

The corrected part of the schema looks like the following:

```
"properties": {
    "pets": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          { // Notice each $ref is encapsulated in it's own block
            "$ref": "#/definitions/cat"
          },
          {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/dog"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Running the following json through gave expected results

```
{"pets":[{"noise":"bark","tail":"long"},{"noise":"meow","tail":"wavy"}]}
[]
{"pets":[{"noise":"bark","tail":"long"},{"noise":"meow","tail":"wavy"},{"noise":"meow","tail":"slinky"},{"noise":"bark","tail":"short"}]}
[]
{"pets":[{"noise":"bark","tail":"long"},{"noise":"meow","tail":"wavy"},{"noise":"meow","tail":"slinky"},{"noise":"bark","tail":"short"},{"noise":"meow","tail":"short"}]}
[$.pets[4]: should be valid to one and only one of the schemas ]
```